# How to take stdin input and break in whitespace in dart?

Tags: dart, input, dart-io

I want to take 5 inputs like

1 2 3 4 5

using a for loop that runs 5 times.

stdin.readLineSync() takes the whitespace as an input and continues until I press ENTER but I want it to separate by whitespace like scanf in C.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you read a line with `readLineSync()`, you can split it by whitespace with [`String.split`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/split.html) and then iterate over the tokens:

```dart
var line = stdin.readLineSync();
var tokens = line.split(RegExp(r'\s+'));
```